# Bottle framework generate pdf

Tags: python, bottle, reportlab, pdflib

I need to generate PDF document using the `Bottle` framework.

I tried similar to `Django` but that didn't work:

```
@bottle.route('/pd')
def create_pdf():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'
    from io import BytesIO
    buffer = BytesIO()
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    p.drawString(100,100,'Hello World')
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottle functions aren't supposed to return the `response` object, they're supposed to return an iterable (string, list, generator, etc.).

So you want this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

@bottle.route('/pd')
def create_pdf():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'

    buffer = BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    p.drawString(100,100,'Hello World')
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    return buffer.getvalue()
```